# mat-option (onSelectionChange) -- the value does not appear correctly

Tags: angular, typescript, autocomplete, angular-material

When I choose city for the first time in its dropdown, the value does not appear. When I then select country in the second dropdown, the first value in the first dropdown appears, and the second value in the second dropdown does not appear. Any suggestions as to what the problem is in my code?

Code.ts

```
  updateForm(event: MatOptionSelectionChange , city: City, country_id: Country, region_id: Region) {
        if (event.source.selected) {
        this.Myform['controls']['country_id'].patchValue(this.country_id.value);
          this.Myform['controls']['city'].patchValue(this.city.value);
        }
    }
```

code.html

```
    <input formControlName="country_id" id="country_id" matInput placeholder="Select Region*" aria-label="State" [matAutocomplete]="auto"
      autoActiveFirstOption [formControl]="country_id">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="updateForm($event,country.id,'country_id')" id="country_id" *ngFor="let country of filteredOptionsCountry | async" [value]="country.name">
        {{ country.name }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete> 

   <input formControlName="city" id="city" matInput placeholder="Select City*" aria-label="State" [matAutocomplete]="auto1"
      autoActiveFirstOption [formControl]="city">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto1="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="updateForm($event,city.id,'city')" *ngFor="let city of filteredOptionsCity | async" [value]="city.name">
        {{ city.name }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Ok what happens is you patch your value with the first call. But in your first call you call this **this.country_id.value** which is **not set** so undefined. In your second call **this.country_id.value** is **set** and will be added.

This might help you understand:

```
updateForm(event: MatOptionSelectionChange , city: any, country_id: any, region_id: any) {
   if (country_id !== ''){
      this.Myform['controls'['country_id'].patchValue(country_id);
   }
   if (city !== '') {
      this.Myform['controls']['city'].patchValue(city);
   }
}
```

And in the HTML:

```
(onSelectionChange)="updateForm($event, city.id, '', '')"

(onSelectionChange)="updateForm($event, '', country.id, '')"
```

Comment: I change like this:   updateForm(event: any, city: any, country_id: any, region_id: any) {
    if (event.isUserInput) {
      this.Myform['controls']['country_id'].patchValue(country_id);
      this.Myform['controls']['city'].patchValue(city);
      this.Myform['controls']['region_id'].patchValue(region_id);
    }
  }

Comment: and html:     <input formControlName="country_id" id="country_id" matInput placeholder="Select Region*" aria-label="State" [matAutocomplete]="auto"
      autoActiveFirstOption [formControl]="country_id">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="updateForm($event,country.country_id,'country_id')" *ngFor="let country of filteredOptionsCountry | async" [value]="country.name">
        {{ country.name }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>

Answer (score 0):

Add this validation and it will fix your problem:
if (event.isUserInput) {

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).